# Why can I attach visual studio to process with no admin rights

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, admin-rights

Well, the title sumarizes my question, but I will elaborate. I have always thought that any process runing with no admin rights shouldn't be able to access the memory space of any other process, and of course shouldnt be able to halt it's execution.

However, with visual studio running under a non-privileged account, I am able to attach to some processes runing under the same account and debug them. Why is this possible? Shouldn't the operative system prevent this?

Thanks in advance and cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for access say memory space of any other process we need open process with `PROCESS_VM_READ|PROCESS_VM_OPERATION|PROCESS_VM_WRITE` .. for this not mandatory need have `SE_DEBUG_PRIVILEGE` - if process running in same session as debugger, have the same token - usually it security descriptor (`DACL`) let open it for this debugger. this is absolutely expected. so question here - are we can open process with full access for debugging ? if this "peer" process (running under same user, with same privileges) - why not ?

and from [DebugActiveProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679295(v=vs.85).aspx) function

> The debugger must have appropriate access to the target process, and
>   it must be able to open the process for **PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS**.
>   **DebugActiveProcess** can fail if the target process is created with a security descriptor that grants the debugger anything less than full
>   access. If the debugging process has the **SE_DEBUG_NAME** privilege
>   granted and enabled, it can debug any process.

and remark from yourself - except  protected processes, if only your debugger when called  **DebugActiveProcess** also protected process (with not less level of protection) (yes this is possible debug protected processes also)

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer. When I studied operative systems in university, I wasnt told about this security management of windows, which i didn't know at all. Based on your answer and some research, now I can better understand this question.

Comment: @DanielGarcíaRubio - any process has security descriptor. we can debug process if we can open it with full access. by default processes in same logon session grant each other. so debugger usual and can debug process from his logon session. another question that elevated or system processes already running in others logon sessions and his SD not grant full access for not elevated debuggers. but `SE_DEBUG_PRIVILEGE` changes the behavior